# Lombok messing up - IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, intellij-idea, lombok

I have Lombok as a dependency (maven), and annotations are imported, but it is not generating the methods. Any suggestions?

Annotations are working:
[image: working annotation]

Methods are not generating:
[image: methods not generating]

Comment: Links to pictures are generally discouraged. Please post the intent of your pictures as code or error messages.

Comment: there are no error messages indicating a solution, the images solely justify my problem along with supplying visuals to help better understand the issue.

Comment: images are fine just post them as uploaded pictures is all (so that we can see them easily in the post without having to click to go somewhere else)

Comment: It may seem rude, but I'm not going to follow somebody with 6 rep's link to a website I don't know, even if it looks like a png. Sorry.

Comment: its gyazo... regardless, the images are not necessary to view, I explain my issue explicity.

Answer (score 2):

You need to install/activate the [lombok plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317) for this to work in IntelliJ. The maven dependency alone, together with the plugin configuration in the pom.xml take only effect in a Maven build:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.12.2</version>
</dependency>
...
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
      <artifactId>lombok-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.12.2.0</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>delombok</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
  ...
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Answer (score 2):

Lombok has actually generated getters in your case, except that your IDE is not showing it for you. That is, your `getKills()` method is visible to `javac` but not to your IntelliJ.

To verify above, you can execute `mvn compile` and you'll see that your code doesn't throw compilation error.

If you're bothered about `getKills()` showing up in red font, you should simply install [Lombok plugin for IntelliJ](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6317). In addition to recognising code generated by Lombok (and not showing in red font), the plugin gives you advantages like auto-complete, ability to 'delombok' within IDE etc.

There is **no explicit need** for installing `lombok-maven-plugin`.

Answer (score 0):

While it's possible that the methods are **actually** not being generated (in which case you should just ignore this answer), but in my experience when I use Lombok in my projects, IntelliJ has **NEVER** been able to detect them in the IDE and always underlines getter/setter calls that I use as errors (even when they are not).

But when I compile and run my code, it works fine because the getters/setters have in fact actually been generated. Try running your code and ignore intellij error underlines.

Comment: alright :) have you looked into a solution for fixing the intellij issue?

Comment: yeah, I tried out a couple lombok plugins but they have had inconsistent rates of success across my 2-3 computers where I run intellij, so I usually just ignore it for the most part (not the greatest solution I know).

Comment: does your code actually run (as in are the getters actually there in the compiled code)

Comment: actually, you need to install the lombok plugin for intellij for it to recognize the annotations! I figured it out yesterday ;)